# Resize table-cell to fit text

Tags: html, css

How can I make the table-cell as small as the text inside it? I tried to set margin, padding and white-space as well, but none of them works:

**HTML**

```
<table class='header_left'>
    <tr>
        <td><a href='/index.php' class='title1'>somewebsite.com</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='vonal'><a href='/index.php' class='title2'>Check something and do it faster than your competitors</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table.header_left {
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.header_left a.title1 {
    color: #e6e8ea;
    font-size: 39px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
table.header_left a.title2 {
    color: #c1c2c4;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin:0;
}
table.header_left td.vonal {
    border-bottom:1px solid #c1c2c4;
    text-decoration:none;
}
table.header_left td {
    border:1px solid;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RZHPD/

As you see, there is padding around the text "somewebsite.com". I want it to be removed.

Thanks

Comment: 'padding around the text "somewebsite.com"' - I cant see that text in your fiddle?

Comment: there is no padding there. You see a space after "somewebsite.com" because the column below it has text of a large length and a table cell expands to fit its content.
Things you could do:
1)not make "somewebsite.com" part of the table
2)center align "somewebsite.com" to make it look better.

Comment: @Pratik: The space after the text is ok. There is a padding-top and a padding-bottom of around 2-5px. That's the problem. What I want is that the top and bottom border of the table-cell be as close to the text as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the default padding of text/ font. you can try adding in your css :

```
table.header_left a.title1 { 
   line-height:15px; 
   float: left;
}
```

Comment: @erdomaster - this will solve your problem. Thanks Era for the solution :)

Comment: The key was the default padding of the text. I didn't want to change the line-height, but now I see it was necessary. Thanks